# How to reset a FormsAuthentication.RenewTicketIfOld Expiration and Issue Date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

So I'm trying to reset a `FormsAuthentication` cookie's **Expiration** and **Issue Date** using the `RenewTicketIfOld` method and it's incrementing the expiration date to an additional 30 minutes from the issue date.

Is it possible possible to change that to just 20 minutes? Or any advice on this matter?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want RenewIfOld to renew at 20 minute increments, the Expiration of the original cookie (a Sliding Expiration value) should be set to expire in 20 minutes as well. It renews at the same rate that the original was issued.

Comment: As per MSDN, `RenewTicketIfOld` calculates new expiration as Current Time + Old Expiration - Old Issue Date. So as Dracorat pointed out if the original different was 20 minutes then only you would get fresh 20 minutes expiration.

Comment: i have this to create a new cookie > var myNewCookie = cntex.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] ?? new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, newCookieValue) { Path = newTicket.CookiePath };  which would be myNewCookie.Expires = {mynewexpirationdate} correct? but it doesn't seem like it's overwriting the old cookie.